# Code platform only accepts manual copy-pasting. How to debug the code locally effeciently?

Tags: debugging, copy-paste-programming

I'm writing a script for a webapp, which I can only copy my code manually to its platform and not push it from my machine. In the code there are parts that use its API and parts that don't. I cannot split it into multiple modules as well. Everything should be on one file.

To be able to debug it on local, I need to change the parts using its API with my own code. However when it's time to upload it then I need to comment my parts and uncomment the API parts. Then undo that to debug again. Is there a way to skip these steps?

I use VS Code. The language is JS. The platform is Fibery.

Comment: What language are you using? I guess the concepts will be the same regardless, but the availability of helpful tools can vary drastically.

Comment: plain javascript

Comment: Why is this question bad?

Comment: @Ooker it's not bad but you could improve it by adding the language you use, the name of the platform if it's openly available to other users etc.

Comment: @mx0 I add that to the question. If it's not bad then why there are 2 downvotes?

Comment: People that place down votes without justification should be shot. I've updated your question to neutralize them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Everything should be in one file**: You can use a tool like *esbuild* to combine ("bundle") many source files (using `import` to refer to each other) into a single file ready to copy and paste. You could even follow it up with a tool that reads the file and puts it into your clipboard for easy pasting (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/749544/1428461).
- **I need to change the parts using its API with my own code**: Most such tools also support "aliases" or "resolutions" that will let you change which files are being imported (e.g. based on an environment variable) without actually changing the source code. Isolate the code that should change into their own file(s) and choose which one(s) get imported based on whether you are testing or deploying. You could also use a different "main" file for each version and then import the common parts in both.
- **I can only copy my code manually to its platform and not push it from my machine**: It may not be worth the trouble, but you could probably use a browser automation tool like *Puppeteer* to do this on your behalf. It's also possible that you could *curl* to whatever endpoint the UI eventually submits your code to.

All tools I mentioned have alternatives and these are just the first examples that came to mind.

Comment: if I can always bundle 3rd party modules into one single file, then what would be the reason for restricting using 3rd party modules at the beginning? I guess it's for security, but then I can always bypassing it?

Comment: @Ooker I don't think it is a security feature, but simply the _lack_ of a "multi file" feature.

Comment: is there any benefit for that?

Comment: @Ooker it's easier for the platform to let you upload / replace one file than to manage multiple

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to wrap it in a `if` that checks for dev/prod environment:

```js
try {
    //calling an object or function that is only available in the product
} catch (error) {
    var isOnIDE = true
}
if (!isOnIDE ) {
    //product code
```

If you want to control this manually, try:

```js
function main(mode='production') {
    if (mode === 'debug' || mode === 1) {
        // debug code
    } else {
        // product code
    }
} 

main('debug')
```

While you still have to edit the `mode` variable when pasting to the platform, at least you don't have to comment and uncomment repeatedly.